# Problem with camera controller when reseting the camera after being idle

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a problem with my camera controller script when reseting the camera after being idle my camera only sets the x axel and not the y axel so it gets pushed back to the ground.

I have tried some things but nothing worked and so i posted this question, i can not find the problem which makes it hard to fix.

Thanks to everyone!

```
 using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float sensitivity = 10f;
    public float cameraDistance = 5f;
    public float rotationTime = 1f;
    public float idleTimeThreshold = 3f;

    private float xRotation;
    private float idleTime;

    private bool isMoving;

    public Vector3 defaultCameraPosition;
    private Quaternion defaultRotation;
    
    public Transform player;
    private Quaternion targetRotation;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        defaultRotation = transform.rotation;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        CameraMovement();
        CheckIdleTimer();
    }

    private void CameraMovement()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

        player.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);

        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -10f, 80f);

        Quaternion playerRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, player.eulerAngles.y, 0f);
        Quaternion verticalRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
        targetRotation = playerRotation * verticalRotation;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, rotationTime);

        Vector3 desiredPosition = player.position - transform.rotation * Vector3.forward * cameraDistance;

        transform.position = desiredPosition;

        isMoving = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D);
    }

    private void CheckIdleTimer()
    {
        if(isMoving || Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") != 0f || Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") != 0f)
        {
            idleTime = 0f;
        }
        else
        {
            idleTime += Time.deltaTime;
            if(idleTime >= idleTimeThreshold)
            {
                ResetCamera();
            }
        }
    }

    private void ResetCamera()
    {
        transform.position = defaultCameraPosition;
        transform.rotation = defaultRotation;
        xRotation = 0f;
        idleTime = 0f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update your post title to reflect the question better. You are running into this issue because `xRotation` is actually controlling the vertical angle of the camera (you alter it with mouseY) and you are resetting the `xRotation` value to 0 in your reset function.